# Relational override on 'objects'?

Tags: alloy

I have a signature

```
sig Test {
    a: Int,
    b: Int,
    c: Int
}
```

If I have two instances (atoms?) of this ( x,y:Test )
can I define a relation between these where only some parameters has changed without having to list all the other parameters as equal?

I want to avoid having to list all unchanged fields
as this can be error-prone assuming I have many fields.

Currently I am using `x.(a+b+c) = y.(a+next[b]+c)` but would like to use something like `x = y ++ (b->next[y.b])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I understand about Alloy I think the answer is No: you cannot talk about all relations where some atom is involved in without explicitly naming these relations. But some experts may correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as it indeed seems to be the case.